# Benefit Of Repository and what is difference between two statements

Tags: c#-4.0

I'm learning the repository pattern. I've implemented it in a sample project. But I don't know what the main benefit of repository is.

```
private IStudentRespostiry repository = null;

public StudentController()
{
    this.repository = new StudentRepository();
}

public StudentController(IStudentRespostiry repository)
{
    this.repository = repository;
}
```

StudentRepository class can also access the method by creating object of the class.

```
StudentRepository obj = new StudentRepository();
```

Anyone have Solid reason for this. One I know in hiding data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reasons for repository people cite are testability and modularity. For testability, you can replace the concrete object with mock one where the repository is used. For modularity you can create different repository, that for example uses different data story.

But I'm highly skeptical of modularity, because repositories are often highly leaky abstractions and changing backed data store is extremely rare. Meaning that something that should be as simple as creating a different instance turns into complete rewrite. Defeating the purpose of repository.

There are [other ways](http://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton) to achieve testability with your data store without worrying about leaky abstractions.

As for your code examples. In first case, first constructor is "default" one and second is probably for either IoC or testing with mocks. IMO there should be no "default" one, because it removes the purpose of actually having an IoC.

Answer (score 1):

The second statement allows [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). This means you can use an [IoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) container to inject the correct implementation.

So for example, in your unit tests you could inject an in memory database (see [mocking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object)) while your production code would use an implementation which hits the actual database.

Comment: Can You Explain Little Bit More

Comment: @RichardRay I added some links and an example. If it still doesn't make sense let me know and I will try to elaborate.